# How to loop a function over a array

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook

So here is the thing I would like to write a function that finds a specific set of numbers. So I have tries a few different ways

I tried this way the Boolean way and kept getting the arguments

```
import numpy as np
N = np.array([10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
def function(N): 
    e = 0
    for i in range(n): 
        if i % 2 == 0: 
            e += a[i]
             sum(e)
```

Got the error for the above code
*TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*

```
import numpy as np
N = np.array([10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
def function(N):
    filter_arr = []
    for item in N:
        if(N% 2 ==0):
            filter_arr.append(True)
        else:
            filter_arr.append(False)
newarr = N[filter_arr]
print(sum(newarr))
```

So here is another attempt to get it right

```
import numpy as np
N = np.array([10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
def function(N):
    for item in N:
        if(N%2 ==0):
            return False
        else:
            return True
        
even_numbers=filter(function, N)

for N in even_numbers:
    print(N)
```

I get a numpy.int32 error

```
def function(N): 
    e = 1
    for i in range(0): 
        if (i % 2 == 0): 
            e *= N[i]
            print(e)
```

This is the closest I have gotten with no error but no result.
So Looking for some help as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what do you want your algorithm to do

Comment: I would like it to give me the product of all the even numbers in the array 2+4+10 ect.

Comment: product or sum you said product and wrote 2+4+10

Comment: ah my fault sum

Comment: no prob everything is covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(array):
    product = 1
    for i in array:
        if i==0:
            continue
        if i%2==0:
            product *= i
    return product
N = np.array([0,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
func(N)
```

Start your variable that will collect your `product` at 1 since it is a multiplication.

If the number is `0` I made a condition to pass it, unless you want to get 0s in your algorithm.

`i%2==0` is just to check if a number has a `rest` of `0` when divided by `2` a.k.a `modulo`.

```
def func1(array):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in array:
        if i%2==0:
            sum1 += i
    return sum1
N = np.array([0,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
func1(N)
```

This code will give you the sum, similar structure, however, `0`s in sum dont matter so you can remove the condition on `0`s.

Comment: Thank you so I was either starting off wrong or didn't have a return at the end. Thank you!

Comment: @tue50771 no prob! . give it one more vote please